# Expo Push Notifications click event

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Did not find in the documentation how to process clicks on the notification
There is only a way to subscribe to notifications and that's it.

```
Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "origin" property for determining whether notification received or selected.

```
_handleNotification = (notification) => {
    if(notification.origin === 'received') {
        // after receive push notification code
    }else if(notification.origin === 'selected'){
        // after click code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ExpoSDK39 and newer, you can check https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Briefly, you can use  Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener and check the `actionIdentifier` property in the response.

```
// adds a listener called whenever user interacts with a notification
// "actionIdentifier": "expo.modules.notifications.actions.DEFAULT",  means user clicked the notification
responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
  console.log("addNotificationResponseReceivedListener", response);
});
```